# Flexibility to have extended and duplicate display with multi monitor setup

Tags: multiple-monitors, extended-desktop

If i setup 3 monitors with my CPU, is it possible for monitor 1 and 2 to share an extended display while monitor 2 and 3 to have a duplicated display?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally possible but it depends on what graphics card you are using, integrated or dedicated, and if the graphics card manufacturer has software to support this.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to duplicate the display, and the monitors have the same resolution then you can easily just split the signal.

[image]

[For example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00083Y4B0)

This is a dumb device, meaning there is no configuration or fancy stuff. Just a plain and simple duplication. They can be purchased for DVI as well.

If you need a more robust setup, Eyefinity cards from AMD can be configured any way you wish.

Or, you can get a [USB to VGA](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=101&cp_id=10114&cs_id=1011403&p_id=8080&seq=1&format=2) or DVI adapter for $30 - $60. These act a graphics card that you can use Windows to clone or set as unique.

Answer (score 0):

Like Mike Stock mentions it depends on your GPU drivers. With nvidia cards for example it is possible trough the nvidia control panel: "**Set up multiple displays**".
There you can **right click** on any extended display and click "**clone with**" to clone it to another connected display.
Just one limitation is that the cloned display need to have the **same resolution** as the original display.